# Project Euler Problem 52: Permuted multiples

Tags: python, programming-challenge

This is my solution to [Project Euler
Problem 52 - Permuted Multiples](https://projecteuler.net/problem=52). In the problem I'm searching for the smallest value of x such that x, 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x, and 6x use the same digits.

```
x = 125874
while True:
    x += 1
    if sorted(set(str(x))) == sorted(set(str(x * 2))) == \
        sorted(set(str(x * 3))) == sorted(set(str(x * 4))) == \
            sorted(set(str(x * 5))) == sorted(set(str(x * 6))):
        print x
        break
```

Is this bad Python? Is there a better way to write this instead of using a `while True` loop? I've tried adding the if condition to the `while` loop, but keep getting an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python lacks C-style techniques like side-effect assignments (`while (++x) { … }`) and counting for-loops (`for (int x = 125874; ; x++) { … }`).  When you find yourself needing a counting loop in Python, a better formulation is nearly always available using either `xrange()`, `itertools`, or a generator.  In this case, I recommend [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

There's nothing in the problem statement that implies that the answer exceeds 125874.  The only logical limit I can see is that the answer needs to have at least six digits.  (The problem is probably designed to make you think about the decimal representation of \$\frac{1}{7}\$.)

Furthermore, manually writing all of the tests for 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 is poor style.

There is no need to transform each set into a sorted list.  Skipping that transformation nearly doubles the speed of the code.

```
from itertools import count

for n in count(100000):
    digits = set(str(n))
    if all(set(str(mult * n)) == digits for mult in xrange(2, 7)):
        print n
        break
```

Comment: Can you explain why the answer has to have at least six digits? Also, the `set` test looks dodgy to me: although it happens to get the correct answer for this problem, it risks false positives. Consider something like `set(str(10525)) == set(str(10525 * 2))`.